# RISC-V ADDI instruction

Tags: riscv

I am currently working on implementing RV32I Base Instruction Set.

I had a question about ADDI instruction. In the manual, how to understand this clause "ADDI rd, rs1, 0 is used to implement the MV rd, rs1 assembler pseudo-instruction."

Does it mean ADDI rd, rs1, 0 is equal to move content of rs1 to register specified by rd?

Answer (score 4):

yes `ADDI rd, rs1, 0` performs the operation :

`rd <- rs1 + 0`, that is `rd <- rs1`

so  `ADDI rd, rs1, 0` performs `MV rd, rs1`

It does not performs a move (copy is a better word) of the content of rs1 to the register specified by rd as mentionned in the question.
It performs a move (copy again) of the content of rs1 to the register rd.

With an example :

`ADDI x3, x5, 0` will copy the content of `x5` to `x3` - and using the same name as above, in this example : `rd` is `x3` and `rs1` is `x5`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `ADDI rd, rs1, 0` is *the* encoding of the `MV rd, rs1` instruction.

Many encodings are possible, e.g. `XORI rd, rs1, 0` would have the same effect.

The reason for specifying which is the chosen encoding is so a disassembler will output `MV rd, rs1` when it sees `ADDI rd, rs1, 0`, but `XORI rd, rs1, 0` will still be disassembled as `XORI rd, rs1, 0`.

Other instructions have specified encodings, such as NOP being `ADDI x0, x0, 0`, rather than any of the other instructions which do nothing.  Note: register 0 is *magic*.  It always reads as zero, thus writes are lost.

`MV` instructions set one register's value equal to another register's value, so they would be better described as "copy", as @LiHenyuan wrote.

Answer (score 2):

The `mv x, y` (move) pseudo-instruction is just an alias for `addi x, y, 0`. That means it's [syntactic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) that is implemented inside the assembler.

Since the `mv` alias is resolved by the assembler `mv` doesn't have its own opcode and thus isn't a real instruction. Hence it's called a pseudo-instruction.

Using the `mv` pseudo-instruction arguably describes the purpose of your code more clearly. Certainly, it's slightly less to type and less to parse for a human.